# How many pixels are in a JTextArea column

Tags: java, swing

If I have a JFrame of fixed size (`preferredSize()` returns a `Dimension` that is 1300 by 900), is there a way to convert the width of a column (used in the `JTextArea(int, int)` constructor) into pixels so I can know exactly how many columns would fit inside te JFrame?

Comment: You could use the [Flow Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: *"so I can know exactly how many columns would fit inside te JFrame?"* That's what `pack()` is for! Which is a reason why *"have a JFrame of fixed size"* is so problematic. It is an arbitrary number that will have the content pane showing at different size on different OS`. General advice, don't build GUIs 'from the outside in', instead start with the size needed for components - then work outwards and pack the frame.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, the problem is, I can't know how what size is needed for the components.  My program shows images as it's main function, and originally I had been using `pack()`, by showing the largest image for a split second, invoking it, then changing the image to the desired one, so that all the images fit.  But with many images I can't load them all to find the largest without a large lag, so there's no good way to know what size I need

Comment: A `JScrollPane` and a resizable frame fix that problem. Throw in a 'size frame to image' button and any user that can't work it, probably should have their license to use a computer revoked.. It's naive to think you can get a content pane of required size by setting the frame size!